# SQL statement to count instances based on a rolling 24 hour windows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some sensor data in a table, as follows:

| Device Id | Heartbeat Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-20 10:25:33 |
| 1 | 2022-11-20 12:31:46 |
| 2 | 2022-11-20 12:31:50 |
| 3 | 2022-11-20 12:32:18 |
| 1 | 2022-11-21 08:25:41 |
| 2 | 2022-11-21 08:25:33 |
| 3 | 2022-11-21 08:25:33 |
| 2 | 2022-11-21 10:25:33 |
| 2 | 2022-11-21 15:25:33 |
| 4 | 2022-11-22 13:25:33 |

I want to write a TSQL statement where I get the number of times each device reported a heartbeat in a rolling 24 hour window for that device. So, in the above case, the result would look like:

| Device Id | Heartbeat Window Start | Heartbeat Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-20 10:25:33 | 3 |
| 2 | 2022-11-20 12:31:50 | 3 |
| 3 | 2022-11-20 12:32:18 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-11-21 15:25:33 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-11-22 13:25:33 | 1 |

Device 1, started its heartbeats at 2022-11-20 10:25:33 and had 3 heartbeats in the next 24 hours window. Device 2 had 3 heartbeats in the 24 hours starting at 12:31:50, but had another heartbeat at 15:25:33 the next day (so it is counted in a new rolling window).

Is there anyway I can write a TSQL for this?

The following query works if I were to group the counts by Date, but my rolling window needs to start from the first instance a device reports its heartbeat. The next group starts at the first record after the 24 hour period following the first/previous record.

```
SELECT DeviceId, Count(*), CONVERT(date, HeartbeatTimestamp)
FROM Table
GROUP BY DeviceId, CONVERT(date, HeartbeatTimestamp)
```

Just came up with this. Unfortunately, this is returning each DeviceId n times when the count is n. So, if Device Id 2 has a count of 3 in the first group, I get 3 rows (each showing the count as 3).

```
SELECT t1.DeviceId, t1.HeartbeatTimestamp, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.DeviceId = t2.DeviceId AND DATEDIFF(hour,t1.HeartbeatTimestamp, t2.HeartbeatTimestamp)<=24 GROUP BY t1.DeviceId,t1.HeartbeatTimestamp
```

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulty. When that happens, you can explain the issue you're having, include the relevant portions of your SQL and data, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help.

Comment: When does the rolling 24 hour window start?...from the first instance of a heartbeat for a particular `Device Id` or is it based on the day (i.e. from midnight to midnight on the same day)?

Comment: @J.D., correct, the rolling window starts at the first instance of a device's heartbeat (with no records of it in the previous 24 hours). If the windows were broken down by calendar days, it would have been easy. A simple 
SELECT DeviceId, Count(*), CONVERT(date, HeartbeatTimestamp) from Table GROUP BY DeviceId, CONVERT(date, HeartbeatTimestamp)

Would suffice. But I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to write the query when the window starts at the first instance of a device's heartbeat.

Comment: KenWhite and DaleK, please see my clarification for J.D. 
I can write the SQL when the rolling window is based on calendar date, but am not sure how to go about writing it the way I need the output. 
And, I am not looking for free coding service. This just happens to be a problem I encountered that I'm trying to solve using SQL (never done anything like this in SQL before) without resorting to writing a C/C++/Python program (that I can easily solve this in).

Comment: Just added. I think there may be a way to join the table to itself as a sub query, but am not very sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive query to find the `Heartbeat Window Start`. Then a simple `GROUP BY` query at the end to gives you the required result.

```
with cte as
(
      select DeviceId, HeartbeatTimestamp, 
             rn = row_number() over (partition by DeviceId
                                         order by HeartbeatTimestamp)
      from   sensors
),
rcte as
(
      select DeviceId, 
             [Heartbeat Window Start] = HeartbeatTimestamp,
             rn
      from   cte
      where  rn = 1

      union all

      select r.DeviceId,
             [Heartbeat Window Start] = case when datediff(second, [Heartbeat Window Start], c.HeartbeatTimestamp) > 24 * 60 * 60
                                             then c.HeartbeatTimestamp
                                             else [Heartbeat Window Start]
                                             end,
             c.rn
      from   rcte r
             inner join cte c on  r.DeviceId = c.DeviceId
                              and r.rn        = c.rn - 1
)
select DeviceId, 
       [Heartbeat Window Start], 
       [Heartbeat Count] = count(*)
from   rcte
group by DeviceId, [Heartbeat Window Start];
```

Comment: Spot on. Thank you so much Squirrel. This produces the result exactly as I wanted to see. I've never worked with partitions or cases before so it is all new to me, but thank you so much for helping out. 
If I may ask one additional extension: If I want to narrow the results to between two dates, where do I add the WHERE clause? at the end or in each sub-query?

Comment: put the condition in `cte`